# Get ACF fields in relationships of returned post

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I know to get the ACF fields of a post it's self but I'm having trouble getting relationships within those results to return ACF fields as well.

example:

```
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'location',
        'post__in'  => array(67)
    );
    $q = new WP_Query($args);
    $locations = array();
    while($q->have_posts()) : $q->the_post();
        $p = get_post(); // gets the basic post details
        $f = get_fields(); // gets the ACF details
        $m = array_merge((array)$p, (array)$f); // merges all details into one array
        array_push($locations, $m);
    endwhile;
```

which shows something like

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 67
            [ACF_Field => This is a custom field/value.
            ...
            [ACF_Relationship_Field] => Array
                (
                    [0] => WP_Post Object
                        (
                            [ID] => 133
                            // there should be another [ACF_Fiel]/value here
                            ...
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

So the first level of array has the ACF Values in it but you can see that the second level does not. I looked at [the ACF Reference](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/) as that's helped me get to this point but unfortunately I haven't found anything that will pull in a relationships with ACF fields attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop for the results and call get_fields() again. So after your code add smt like:

```
foreach( $locations as $l ) {
   //grab post id
   $pid = $l['ACF_Relationship_Field'][0]->ID;
   // grab fields
   $fields = get_fields($pid);
   // add them back. As ACF_Relationship_Field is an object I will add it next
   // to it, but you can do whatever you prefer
   $l['ACF_Relationship_Field'][] = $fields;

}
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be a more seamless way but this works too.